# Customizing Auto-Build for multiple C++-Projects

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build, build-process, devenv

Hy guys,

for a project at the university we're faced with the following problem:

For coverage analysis purposes we should instrument the code of several C++-Projects, which are automatically build via a VBScript using devenv. Before the actual build process we have to add 3 things:

1. A new VC++-Directory, with the path to the Cl-Wrapper.exe which does the instrumentation (needs to be first entry).
2. Additional command line commands for the C\C++-Compiler.
3. Additional command line commands for the Linker.

We tried to solve this via an Add-In, launched through the /Command switch for devenv. Sadly this doesn't work. After a little search, we found thats MSBuild might solve our problem via an additional configuration. For me it looks like that this could be done only for a certain project. But we are looking for a project independent way to execute the 3 stepa above before the build process.

Is there any possibility to achieve this with devenv/MSBuild?

Thanks so far..